# how to solve value error x must be 1d pie chart

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pie-chart

Using fifa 2018 data to plot a preferred foot pie chart. initialized left and right, getting error when calling them in `plt`.

```py
left = fifa.loc[fifa['Preferred Foot'] == 'Left'].count(0)
right = fifa.loc[fifa['Preferred Foot'] == 'Right'].count(0)
print(left[0])
print(right[0])
        
plt.pie(x=[left,right])
plt.show()
```

Comment: what's the error? also why is your code indented like that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.